# generating method name in a macro

Tags: c++, macros

I need to automatically prepend  method name to some logging messages. I've been using `__FUNCTION__` to do it but it generates the fully qualified name of the method ( namespace::class:method ). So it's wasting a lot of space and makes logs less readable. Is there any way to append only the method name in a MACRO, without any unnecessary qualifiers?

Answer (score 1):

If your logging code looks like this:

```
#define LOGCALL \
    clog << "Called " << __FUNCTION__ << endl;
```

then you can simply write a global function to trim the function name as required and say:

```
#define LOGCALL \
    clog << "Called " << MyTrim( __FUNCTION__ ) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that takes a char* argument and returns a pointer to the function name in it.
Then write

```
MyFunction(FUNCTION)
```

Instead of

```
FUNCTION
```

This has also the advantage that you can dynamically switch between short and long names.